# Insert unexisted data and denying existed data in Laravel Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, import

I'm using Laravel Excel by https://laravel-excel.com/. I have a CSV file that has data like:

[image]

I want to import some CSV and validate the existed data and not inserting it into database.

But, I want to insert data that not existed in database and I don't know how to validate it.

I just want to insert the new data together and denying the old one for the purpose of preventing some duplicate data after importing CSV into a database and reducing human error.

I have example code like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports\Points;

use App\Models\PointRegular;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;

class PointsRegularImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            // Check existing data in database
            $pointRegulars = PointRegular::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->where('product_id', $row['product_id'])
            ->where('channel_id', $row['channel_id'])
            ->where('transaction_type_id', $row['transaction_type_id'])
            ->where('payment_method_id', $row['payment_method_id'])
            ->get();

            foreach($pointRegulars as $pointRegular) {
                // Check for update data with id
                if($row->has('id')) {
                    if($pointRegular->id == $row['id']) {
                        $point = PointRegular::findOrFail($row['id']);
                        $point->product_id = $row['product_id'];
                        $point->channel_id = $row['channel_id'];
                        $point->transaction_type_id = $row['transaction_type_id'];
                        $point->payment_method_id = $row['payment_method_id'];
                    }
                } else {
                    // Create new data
                    // Check for data existed in database
                    // If exist, deny existed data and insert new data
                    if($pointRegular) {
                        return "Existed and not insert";
                    } else {
                        return "You Inserting new data without creating the old one";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want skip exist value you can query with IGNORE, or if you want update same value you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: "Ignore" is the same of insertOrIgnore()  in laravel right?

Comment: Exactly [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts)

Comment: Oh i see, but using that function, gonna be check all data.
I just want  unique column like to check, product_id, channel_id, etc. how's that?

Comment: Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624473/laravel-5-1-create-or-update-on-duplicate)

Comment: Yea, it's seem okay using updateOrCreate, hahaha.. thank you mate

Comment: You are welcome ;) flag my answer please

Answer (score 0):

Using `updateOrCreate` with Eloquent reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

```
function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = []){}
```